# Incorrect alignment for math equations

Tags: math-mode

Hi im trying to show some math relationships in two columns

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,amsmath, mathtools}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}[c]
1\\[10pt]
\delta{(t)}\\[10pt]
u(t)\text{\footnotemark}\\[10pt]
sgn(t)\text{\footnotemark}\\[10pt]
rect(t)\\[10pt]
sinc(t)\\[10pt]
tri(t)\\[10pt]
sinc^2(t)\\[10pt]
\end{aligned}
\qquad\xlongleftrightarrow{\mathscr{F}}\qquad
\begin{aligned}[c]
&2\pi\delta{(\omega)}\\[10pt]
&1\\[10pt]
&\pi\delta{(w)}+\frac{1}{j\omega}\\[10pt]
&\frac{2}{jw}\\[10pt]
&sinc(\frac{\omega}{2\pi})\\[10pt]
&rect(\frac{\omega}{2\pi})\\[10pt]
&sinc^2(\frac{\omega}{2\pi})\\[10pt]
&tri(\frac{\omega}{2\pi})\\[10pt]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

But the output does not align the equations correctly.
[image: Fourier transform pairs]

Comment: As the items in the two aligned have different heights they of course does not align. In stead use a single construction and multiple alignment points

Comment: Could you provide me with a basic example that would allow me to use the format I desire above?

Comment: also never use math italic for multi-letter words such as rect, the font is designed to separate the letters to look like a product of variables not a word

Comment: Ok so just surround the rect,tri sinc in a \text{} ?

Comment: @JS60 no, no, no please don't use `\text` for that, it is **not**  what it is mena to be used for, if they do not already exists, define them using `\DeclareMathOperator`

Comment: Ok thanks, will do, still unsure how to align the equations to get the layout I want... Will keep working at it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example to show the alignment, still not sure what those `\footnotemark` are for

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,amsmath, mathtools}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\DeclareMathOperator\sinc{sinc}
\DeclareMathOperator\sgn{sgn}
\DeclareMathOperator\rect{rect}
\DeclareMathOperator\tri{tri}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
&1 &&&& 2\pi\delta{(\omega)} \\
&\delta{(t)}&&&& 1 \\
&u(t)\text{\footnotemark}&&&& \pi\delta{(w)}+\frac{1}{j\omega} \\
&\sgn(t)\text{\footnotemark}&&&& \frac{2}{jw} \\
&\rect(t)&& 
\qquad\xlongleftrightarrow{\mathscr{F}}\qquad
&& \sinc(\frac{\omega}{2\pi}) \\
&\sinc(t)&&&& \rect(\frac{\omega}{2\pi}) \\
&\tri(t)&&&& \sinc^2(\frac{\omega}{2\pi}) \\
&\sinc^2(t)&&&& \tri(\frac{\omega}{2\pi} 
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative with `array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,mathtools}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\begin{array}{lcl}
1                           &   &2\pi\delta(\omega)                 \\
\delta{(t)}                 &   &1                                  \\
u(t)\text{\footnotemark}    &   &\pi\delta{(w)}+\frac{1}{j\omega}   \\
sgn(t)\text{\footnotemark}  &   &\frac{2}{jw}                       \\
rect(t)                     &   &sinc(\frac{\omega}{2\pi})          \\
sinc(t)                     &   &rect(\frac{\omega}{2\pi})          \\
tri(t)                      &   &sinc^2(\frac{\omega}{2\pi})        \\
sinc^2(t)                   &
        \multirow{-8}*{$\qquad\xlongleftrightarrow{\mathscr{F}}\qquad$}
                                &tri(\frac{\omega}{2\pi})
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

The `sinc`, `tri`, etc are function names, they should be in upright shape, i.e. declare them as math operators (`\DeclareMathOperator\sinc{sinc}`, ...) as is done in other answers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use some sort of array, if you want to keep entries aligned with one another.

For the middle arrow, there are two possibilities: set it in the vertical center or at the top. Take your pick.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,amsmath, mathtools,array}
\usepackage{extarrows}

\DeclareMathOperator\sinc{sinc}
\DeclareMathOperator\sgn{sgn}
\DeclareMathOperator\rect{rect}
\DeclareMathOperator\tri{tri}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{array}{@{} >{\displaystyle}l c >{\displaystyle}l @{}}
1 &\hphantom{\xlongleftrightarrow{\mathscr{F}}}& 2\pi\delta{(\omega)} \\
\delta{(t)} && 1 \\
u(t)\text{\footnotemark} && \pi\delta{(w)}+\frac{1}{j\omega} \\
\sgn(t)\text{\footnotemark} && \frac{2}{jw} \\
\rect(t) && \sinc\Bigl(\frac{\omega}{2\pi}\Bigr) \\
\sinc(t) && \rect\Bigl(\frac{\omega}{2\pi}\Bigr) \\
\tri(t) && \sinc^2\Bigl(\frac{\omega}{2\pi}\Bigr) \\
\sinc^2(t) && \tri\Bigl(\frac{\omega}{2\pi}\Bigr)
\end{array}
\settowidth{\dimen0}{$\displaystyle\pi\delta{(w)}+\frac{1}{j\omega}$}
\makebox[0pt][r]{%
  $\xlongleftrightarrow{\mathscr{F}}$%
  \hspace{\dimen0}%
  \hspace{2\arraycolsep}%
}
\end{equation*}

\bigskip

\begin{equation*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{array}{@{} >{\displaystyle}l c >{\displaystyle}l @{}}
1 &\xlongleftrightarrow{\mathscr{F}}& 2\pi\delta{(\omega)} \\
\delta{(t)} && 1 \\
u(t)\text{\footnotemark} && \pi\delta{(w)}+\frac{1}{j\omega} \\
\sgn(t)\text{\footnotemark} && \frac{2}{jw} \\
\rect(t) && \sinc\Bigl(\frac{\omega}{2\pi}\Bigr) \\
\sinc(t) && \rect\Bigl(\frac{\omega}{2\pi}\Bigr) \\
\tri(t) && \sinc^2\Bigl(\frac{\omega}{2\pi}\Bigr) \\
\sinc^2(t) && \tri\Bigl(\frac{\omega}{2\pi}\Bigr)
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]